# What language codes are available in manifest file

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge

In my manifest file I have currently just one language setting.

> Resource Language="en-us"

I want to make the app to work in all english stores (e.g. UK), which parameter should I choose? 
 Also, my App has multiple languages supported natively, so I need above codes for spanish, french, german and dutch languages, all regions, where can I find the corresponding codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the language tags in the list of [languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/supported-languages?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) supported by the Windows Store.

Just specify the list of your app's supported language in the [Resources element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn934770?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) inside your app's manifest file.

Additionally, here is an [sample app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa) for manage languages and region setting.

For more details, you may refer to [Specify the supported languages in the app's manifest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/manage-language-and-region#specify-the-supported-languages-in-the-apps-manifest).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Table of Language Culture Names, Codes, and ISO Values Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx) where you can find language code for UK: `en-GB` and other